# Origin of UIView doesn't change according to constrains

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uiview, constraints

I've a problem that I can't solve because I'm missing a little detail to explain the following situation.

I've an `UIView` with a Vertical Space Constraint to be on the bottom on the screen.

On a 3.5", the origin of my `UIView` is (0,447).
On a 4", the origin is the same but on the simulator's screen the `UIView` is **at the good position** (bottom).

I need this origin to put correctly my view according to the keyboard below.

It's important to note that this origin (0,447) is the origin I can read on Xcode thanks to Interface Builder.
I'm catching this origin on the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
basicOriginCommentView = commentView.frame.origin;
```

I've join a screenshot of my Interface Builder.
[image: screenshot]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want the UIVie to move up when the keyboard is displayed? and down again when its not?

Comment: Exactly. This is perfectly working for a 3.5" because I have the good `basicOriginCommentView`. But for a 4" it's not working. This origin doesn't change while the `commentView` is well positioned. My only problem is to find why this origin is not changed even though the view is well positioned.
Maybe it's because the `basicOriginCommentView` is caught before the `commentView` was positioned. Is it possible ? (I'm creating it on `viewDidLoad` method)

Comment: Why not attach this view to UIKeyboard's accessory view? That way it will always be displayed when the keyboard is presented?

Comment: I didn't know that before developing this. Now it's working so I won't change everything. My only problem is about this view origin.. Everything works good after that. By the way if the implementation of this is easy to do, why not. Does this view always visible even if the keyboard is not ?

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you're thinking about ?

Comment: The only problem I see if when the keyboard is not visible, neither will this view be visible, which i think is not what you want. I'm not sure what else to suggest, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different ways to solve this problem.

On Interface Builder, I manually increase the y to be perfectly align with the bottom for the 4" device. It was working perfectly for a 4" but I have the same problem for the 3.5".

Finally I saved the origin far after the `viewDidLoad` method.
Just when my keyboard will appear, I save the position of the `contentView`. At this time the origin is the good one.

That means I have no idea why the origin was not good when I saved the origin on the `viewDidLoad` method.

Anyway, problem solved.